# Lag when authenticating local user on Game Center

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, game-center

For my cocos2d game, I authenticate the local user in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method of my AppDelegate. However, whenever the authentication is complete, it will cause a short lag in my game when the little "Welcome back, X" message slides down and back up. The problem is I have no control over when this authentication is complete – obviously the duration is highly dependent on the data connection of the device.

Sometimes the message (and the un-avoidable accompanying lag) appears as soon as when I am in the menu scene, which is somewhat acceptable, since my menu is more or less static. More often than not, it happens later, when the game has already started. Because my game is an endless scroller, the message always causes a lag in the movement of the player, even causing the player to die sometimes (half a second of lag is enough :-/).

How might I circumvent this? I used to have a loading scene right before my menu scene to load some of my assets, and because the loading takes a while, there was always a good chance that the authentication is completed at the loading scene, but of course I can't guarantee that it will be true!

Answer (score 1):

Game Center can make the game freeze for a little as its starts if your connection isn't great. I doubt that loading GameCenter on a different thread would be a good idea (or even have an effect on that) but what you could do as a work around of the issue you are having is to give the game a 3-2-1 countdown before it starts scrolling/moving. would give a little more time for game center and time for the player to build his focus, starting serious in a game straight away might not be to the liking of some players.
I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.. In fact, I do have a 3-2-1 countdown but many times the pop-down still ends up appearing after the countdown. I guess this lag can't really be avoided then!

Comment: I've seen that lag in MANY well known titles on iPhone and iPad, so you may try on a more stable connection and see how it goes, but yeah, I'm afraid you are sort of stuck with it.

Comment: This happens a lot in Temple Run. It might not be a bad idea to set a bool in your gc manager class that you set to false when the game starts, which if set to false, keeps your ping method from sending an authentication req to gc.