# Gamecenter init/authentication makes SpriteKit's sprite movement lagging

Tags: ios, ios7, game-center, sprite-kit

I have a simple scenario (default SpriteKit template): one `ViewController` and a `MyScene` SpriteKit scene.
In my ViewController I managed in `viewDidLoad` the gamecenter initialization but my scene after start immediatelly starts a rather quick sprite movement infinitely (a background parallax scrolling).

Everything works correctly but **until GameCenter goes through the authentication procedure my sprite movement lags, breaks, not running fluently.**

What practice can I have to minimize this (with keeping the parallax sprite movement running)?

I'm testing this on iPhone4 device (IOS7.03)

Comment: Did u try Instruments what is/are the problematic call(s)?

Comment: Yeah, tried to profile, but Instruments crashed (with XCode 5.0)

Comment: This is duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450281/lag-when-authenticating-local-user-on-game-center?rq=1 It's not specific to SpriteKit, so in that respect it's also a better phrased question than this one.

Comment: A similar slowdown occurs if you use Multipeer Connectivity but forget to stop advertising/browsing for services because this will hamper the speed of transmitting packets from peer to peer. Perhaps it's the same here, possibly caused by frequently initiating Game Center authentication or other methods. Impossible to tell without any code though.

Answer (score 1):

GameCenter authentication is actually something that has been causing lag in games for awhile.  There are a couple ways people try to get around it, and it's really depends on the app and programmers taste.

1. Pause the game during GameCenter authentication
   This is the easiest way typically, and pretty straightforward.
2. Put the authentication on another thread
   If you desire a fluid option from menu to gameplay, this would be the route to go.
   Just use GCD to start a new thread and run the GameCenter authentication in it.

Hope this helps.  There might be a couple of other ways, but these are the two I've seen the most.  I typically just use the first method.

Comment: Thx Milam, regarding No1, u suggest to keep the app still until localPlayer.authenticateHandler delivers the isAuthenticated==YES?

Comment: Yes.  The game doesn't start until isAuthenticated returns true. I would like to add I don't just keep it still though, I use a little waiting pop up with an animated timer to let the user know it's not just a random freeze(like what might occur if you hadn't paused it yourself). Users are used to loading screens.